# Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

I got `AttributeError` when attempting to get a value for field `client` on serializer `ClientSerializer`.

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.

#### models.py

```
class Box(models.Model):
    box = models.IntegerField()
    controller = models.ForeignKey(Controller, related_name='boxes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.box)


class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cpf = models.IntegerField()
    box = models.OneToOneField(
    
        Box,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client
```

#### serializers.py

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = [
            "id",
            "client",
            "cpf",
            "box",
        ]

class BoxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = [
            "id",
            "box",
            "controller"
        ]
```

#### views.py

```
class ClientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, store_pk=None, locker_pk=None, controller_pk=None, box_pk=None):
        queryset = Client.objects.filter(box=box_pk, box__controller=controller_pk, box__controller__locker=locker_pk, box__controller__locker__store=store_pk)
        serializer = ClientSerializer(queryset, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, store_pk=None, locker_pk=None, controller_pk=None, box_pk=None):
        queryset = Client.objects.filter(box=box_pk, box__controller=controller_pk, box__controller__locker=locker_pk, box__controller__locker__store=store_pk)
        client = get_object_or_404(queryset)
        serializer = ClientSerializer(client, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm trying to get the object client on `lockers/1/controllers/1/boxes/1/client/`
which is `OneToOneField` relations with boxes and It's in a nested router
I already tried use decorator `@action` but yet didn't work.

Anyone know why it's not finding the correct object attribute ?

Comment: Because a *collection* of objects has not the attributes of the elements in that collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `list` method you should use `many=True` parameter when you're creating a new serializer instance:

```
serializer = ClientSerializer(queryset, context={'request': request}, many=True)
```

In case of `retrieve` only one object should be received. Instead of

```
client = get_object_or_404(queryset)
```

you should call `first()`, `last()` (or most basically and clearly - `.get(pk=pk)`) on queryset to **retrieve** only one item from QuerySet. Then you should just execute:

```
# client is one of elements of your queryset
serializer = ClientSerializer(client, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: Thank you bro, Now it's clear to me 
I didn't realize what the method was returning